# MySQL optimizing buffer_pool_size among buffer_pool_instances - where is the trade off?

Tags: mysql, innodb, optimization, buffer-pool

I'm looking to optimize MySQL INNODB by tuning buffer pool individual instances.

According to the MySQL documentation:

> "The total size you specify is divided among all the buffer pools. For best efficiency, specify a combination of `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size` so that each buffer pool instance is at least 1 gigabyte."

However, this doesn't specify the optimum approach to defining  innodb_buffer_pool_size. Which of these is considered a better approach:

a) a larger number of smaller buffers (given that each buffer instance is >1GB)

e.g. 45 buffers instances over 50GB buffer pool

or

b) a smaller number of larger buffers

e.g 5 buffer instances over 50GB buffer pool

?

Comment: The number of instances has only a small impact on performance.  Simply go with the rules (1) 1GB each but (2) not more than 16.